# Оптимизация , поиск параметров . апроксимация

Tags: r

есть функция которая создает синусоиду  `ms`

```
ms <- function(amplitude,frequency,phase){
time <- seq(0, 2 * pi, pi/200)
sinusoid <- amplitude * cos(time * frequency - phase)
return(sinusoid)
}

s1 <- ms(amplitude = am,frequency = fr,   0)
s2 <- ms(amplitude = am/2,frequency = fr*3,   0)
plot(s1,t="l")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть некий вектор `Y` со значениями

```
Y <- cumsum(rnorm(400))
plot(Y,t="l")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача : описать суммой двух синусоид вектор Y чтобы корреляция между ними и вектором Y была максимальной. Или если сказать по другому то нужно найти 6 параметров синусоид, амплитуду, фазу, частоту  для двух синусоид

Comment: спасибо, что рассказали нам всем, какую перед вами поставили задачу. надеюсь, когда вы её решите, напишете ответ с решением. это будет полезно для других людей, которым тоже могут поставить подобную задачу.

Comment: Извините я не очень понял)) Это был сарказм?